# Spring Boot controller test - assert static HTML response

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am trying to write a unit test to verify that a request returns the content of a static html file. The page is rendered when running the server, but there is no content in the test response.

Controller class:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class IndexControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnIndexPage() throws Exception {
        File index = new ClassPathResource("static/index.html").getFile();
        String html = new Scanner(index).useDelimiter("\\z").next();

        mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("index.html"))
                .andExpect(content().string(html));
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:

I've got a working test which involves actually starting the server. My goal however was to not have to do that, by using `@WebMvcTest`. Not sure if that's possible or not. I consider this a workaround (unless it's the only way) and am still looking for a solution (that doesn't require starting the server).

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class IndexControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Test
    public void shouldReturnIndexPage() throws Exception {
        File index = new ClassPathResource("static/index.html").getFile();
        String html = new Scanner(index).useDelimiter("\\z").next();

        String responseBody = restTemplate.getForObject("/", String.class);

        assertThat(responseBody).isEqualTo(html);
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but can you try what will be shown on page if you will change return "index.html"; to whatever like return "hello there";?

Comment: Seems like you are abusing Spring, the framework designed to return JSONs in most cases. And in simpler scenarios, you can return primtives. Please explain more about your setup, and I recommend also to read Spring docs and how to build a webapp with Spring. https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: @Pavlo As I said, the page is rendered correctly. It is in the test case that it doesn't work. I can add that `andExpect(view().name("index.html"))` is successful, which (afaik) means that Spring understands that the index page should be rendered.

Comment: @hagai Not sure how this would be considered "abusing Spring"? Spring initializr is generating this code structure for me and this is how it's done in most examples I've seen. It's just the test setup I can't figure out.

Comment: If you have a solution, you should post it as an answer, not an edit to your question. Please post your solution as an answer, and roll your question back to a state where it does not include the answer.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I wouldn't consider it a solution, but a workaround. If it is the solution I still need to get that explained.

Comment: @cjglimsjo _you_ called it a "solution" in your edit ;) - you should edit this to make it clear you are still looking for a solution and make sure to declare that what you have in your answer is not the solution you are looking for.

Comment: @cjglimsjo if you will reveal the whole setup and what you are trying to do I can suggest you what is considered a good practice for your use case. what is your client-side framework? Have you tried using spring boot?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton you are right, thanks!

Comment: @hagai I am using Spring Boot as it says in the title. I tried to figure it out by reading the documentation without success.

Comment: What client side framework are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I came across this question facing the same issue, I managed to build a test using the **MockMvc** like this

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class homePageControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void testIndex() throws Exception{
        File login = new ClassPathResource("static/login.html").getFile();
        String html = new String(Files.readAllBytes(login.toPath()));

        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/login.html"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(html))
                .andDo(print());
    }
}
```

When testing by doing http request, you have to spawn the whole server, so he can handle the request i.e headers, status and such

hope it helps